# 'She drunk lots of beer' or 'She has drunk lots of beer'

Tags: present-perfect

I am confused about the following two sentences:

> **'She drunk lots of beer'**

or

> **'She has drunk lots of beer'**

In the Present Perfect Tense, which sentence is correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **She drunk lots of beer**

The sentence above is grammatically incorrect. "She *drank* lots of beer" (a simple past tense sentence) should be used instead if you simply want to talk about the action that has happened in the past.

> **She has drunk lots of beer**

The sentence above is grammatically correct, and *is* the Present Perfect Tense.

Comment: clarification helps in confusion. thaks +1

Answer (score 1):

She drunk lots of beer.

She has drunk lots of beer.

You form the present perfect tense for the third person singular  by putting the auxiliary verb has before a past participle. So the second sentence is in the present perfect tense.

As for the first sentence, this is not grammatical.

You use "drank" as the second form of the verb "drink" to form the simple past tense, though some people also use "drunk" in informal speaking.  So the sentence in the simple past tense is:

She drank a lot of beer.

Comment: Thanks for more information, +1 ..